# How to add condition in the react-router v6 element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am updating my project from v5 to v6 of react-router-dom.
But there is a catch

In v5, this is working

```
   <Route path={`${url}/phases/:phaseIndex`}>
            {(chosenPhase?.type === PhaseType.intervention ||
              chosenPhase?.type === PhaseType.observation) && (
              <AssessmentPhaseDetails
                study={study!.item as Study}
                returnPath={url}
              />
            )}

            {chosenPhase?.type === PhaseType.enrollment && (
              <EnrollmentPhaseDetails
                study={study!.item as Study}
                returnPath={url}
              />
            )}

            {chosenPhase?.type === PhaseType.screening && (
              <ScreeningPhaseDetails
                study={study!.item as Study}
                returnPath={url}
              />
            )}
          </Route>
```

But in v6 when I add nested ternary operator
Its giving me this error `Line 531:15:  Do not nest ternary expressions`

v6 codes. How can I solve this?

```
<Route
            path="/phases/:phaseIndex"
            element={
              chosenPhase?.type === PhaseType.intervention ||
              chosenPhase?.type === PhaseType.observation ? (
                <AssessmentPhaseDetails
                  study={study!.item as Study}
                  returnPath={pathname}
                />
              ) : chosenPhase?.type === PhaseType.enrollment ? (
                <EnrollmentPhaseDetails
                  study={study!.item as Study}
                  returnPath={pathname}
                />
              ) : (
                chosenPhase?.type === PhaseType.screening && (
                  <ScreeningPhaseDetails
                    study={study!.item as Study}
                    returnPath={pathname}
                  />
                )
              )
            }
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Routing
Lets say we want to render a component only if a state is true for example if a user is logged in, we can do that like this:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="start"
  element={
    loggedIn ? (
      <Start />
    ) : (
      <Navigate replace to={"/"} />
    )
  }
/>
```

Basically here we are checking if the loggedIn state is true. If it is, we return the Start component, however if it is false, we redirect the user to the homepage using the Navigate element.

The replace prop simply replaces the current location with the given path instead of adding on to it.